# how to scrape the data from the url in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping actually what I need is by using this URL: http://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/ there are 37116 jobs are there i want to scrape all the company information ( 37116 jobs company information ). which is in the View job details in the above mentioned url. Any one please help me to solve this task.

Comment: Show us your code, and what you've tried ! also include which information you are trying to parse there?

Comment: attempting to make request/call 37,000 + times is a pretty tall order. Also, you might want to read the site's terms and conditions as it looks like they prohibit  "...using or attempting to use engines, manual or automated software, tools, devices, agents, scripts robots or other means, devices, mechanisms or processes (including, but not limited to, browsers, spiders, robots, avatars or intelligent agents) to navigate, search, access, “scrape,” “crawl,” or “spider” any web pages or any Services provided on the Sites other than the search engine and search agents available..."

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, Thanks for your concern, I got the data which you shared the CSV format. I need code and how it works and I want to learn because of I'm new to web scraping. Thanks

Comment: @chitown88 check my answer below :P

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, oh great idea! of course 37116 jobs doesn't necessarily mean 37116 different companies, just get the list of unique companies and you greatly reduced then required calls needed. Brilliant!

Comment: @chitown88 yea also he will just need `concurrent.futures` to speed up the process :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following `url`:

https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page=&listings_per_page=&view=list

Here's two parameter which you will edit `page=` and `listings_per_page=`:

Currently the website do have `37091` Jobs.

After my testing, I do see that `listings_per_page` is limited by `1000` per one page.

Example: https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page=1&listings_per_page=1000&view=list

So you will need to loop from `page=1` to `page=38` and set `listings_per_page=1000`

Which means `1000` result per page * `38` page = `38000`

**After that**:

You will collect all links and pass it to `list` with condition to remove duplicates in case if you worry about `sort`. Otherwise just pass it to `set` which doesn't accept duplicates but it's don't care about `sort`. Then you can parse each `url` in `list` or `set` to collect the information.

By The Way, I'll loop over `371` page and each page include 100 items so i will get `37100` `url` **(or less if the last page have little than 100 url)** and remove the duplicates from, then parse:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

links = []
try:
    for item in range(1, 372):
        print(f"Extraction Page# {item}")
        r = requests.get(
            f"https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page={item}&listings_per_page=100&view=list")
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for item in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'captions-field'}):
                for a in item.findAll('a'):
                    a = a.get('href')
                    if a not in links:
                        links.append(a)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Good Bye!")
    exit()

data = []
try:
    for link in links:
        r = requests.get(link)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'compProfileInfo'}):
                a = [a.text.strip() for a in item.findAll('span')]
                if a[6] == '':
                    a[6] = 'N/A'
                data.append(a[0:7:2])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Good Bye!")
    exit()

while True:
    try:
        with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(['Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Website'])
            writer.writerows(data)
            print("Operation Completed")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please Close The File")
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Good Bye")
        exit()
    break
```

Result Can Be Viewed Here:
[Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a7d3e60e56bbea29135eda11a9d78805/output.csv)

> The output is 1885 Rows because I've let the script to remove duplicated `links` for companies before i parsed.

Run Code Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/desioptcom)

Comment: @ahmed American, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through this URL by replacing `page=1` from 1 to 371: http://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?searchId=1575377155.0222&action=search&page=1&listings_per_page=100&view=list and get all a tags of view details using xpath `//*[@class="viewDetails"]/a/@href` then get all the details required from the respective pages.